# MacOS severely slow internet connection

Tags: macos, network, wifi

I am running MacOS 13.3.1 (22E261) on MacBook Pro 2019 and ever since about 4 months ago my internet speed is severely reduced and it seems to be getting worse. I've tested speed with fast.com and it's 2.5 MBit/s, while iPhone connected to the same Wi-Fi gets about 50 MBit/s. How would I diagnose this issue? Has anyone else encountered this?

There seems to be some packet loss there:

```
 ping google.com
PING google.com (142.251.36.142): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=0 ttl=119 time=16.640 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=1 ttl=119 time=86.960 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=4 ttl=119 time=164.355 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=5 ttl=119 time=202.139 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=6 ttl=119 time=228.467 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=7 ttl=119 time=33.433 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=8 ttl=119 time=21.734 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=9 ttl=119 time=38.683 ms
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=10 ttl=119 time=53.335 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
64 bytes from 142.251.36.142: icmp_seq=11 ttl=119 time=1201.508 ms
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
```

Comment: Testing WiFi speeds is just shy of guess work; there’s simply too many variables like interference from electrical devices, other WiFi signals, etc.  Compounding the issue is that you’re not just testing your connection, but going over the internet where there are also too many variables.  Start by plugging in directly to the router and testing speeds.  Then build from there.

Comment: Also, don’t use `ping`. Use the command `traceroute <hostname/ip_address>` instead.  It will show you every connection made between your device and the end server as well as the response times for each.  You might be surprised where things slow down.